# Where is the varnish configuration file?

Tags: webserver, configuration-files, varnish

I have just installed varnish and its ready to serve web pages.

Problem is that we are hitting open files limit.
We have already set `ulimit` to varnish user.

We want to find a file where  we can write this configuration:

```
# Maximum number of open files
NFILES=131072

# Locked shared memory, default log size is 82MB + header
MEMLOCK=82000

## Configuration with VCL
#
# Listen on port 80, administration on localhost:6082, and forward to
# one content server selected by the vcl file, based on the request.  Use a
# fixed-size cache file.
#
# Note: you must replace "example.org" with the outside IP address of your server
# - this is the address at which Varnish receives incoming requests.
# $wgSquidServers in MediaWiki's LocalSettings.php will also need to list all addresses for this Varnish cache.
#
DAEMON_OPTS="-a example.org:80 \
             -T localhost:6082 \
             -f /etc/varnish/default.vcl \
             -u varnish -g varnish \
             -s file,/var/lib/varnish/varnish_storage.bin,4G"
```

Answer (score 30, accepted):

The file you're looking for is the Varnish daemon config script. You can find this (usually) in the `/etc/sysconfig/varnish` if you're on Redhat/RHEL, or `/etc/default/varnish` if you're on Debian/Ubuntu

Comment: Take a look and see if you can see a varnish file in `/etc/defaults` or `/etc/sysconfig`. This appears to be the file you're looking for.

Comment: Found mine at `/etc/varnish`

Answer (score 15):

There are two places that you will need to do varnish configuration:

1. `/etc/default/varnish`
2. `/etc/varnish/default.vcl`

Comment: Second path may be different, but if, it's defined in first file, so start searching there.

Answer (score 9):

This is on centos linux server

```
/etc/sysconfig/varnish
/etc/varnish/default.vcl
```

you will also have to change httpd config file to change the port if you want to put varnish in front of apache

```
/etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf
```

Source: [How to install and configure Varnish with Apache on Centos 6](http://namhuy.net/2372/how-to-install-and-configure-varnish-with-apache-on-centos-6.html)

Answer (score 6):

It's also worth noting that reloading the varnish config after editing clears it's cache.