# Is it possible to have VCL file definitions made dynamic

Tags: varnish, varnish-vcl

Behavior of Apache Server can be controlled from a variety of configuration file but they boil down to two locations -
1) a .conf file in the apache installation folder 
2) .htaccess file

Can Varnish be configured in a similar way so that it can take up vcl definitions in real time..

Answer (score 0):

Varnish take VCL rules from /etc/varnish/default.vcl[¹](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9422225/where-is-the-varnish-configuration-file), you can modify those rules and do `sudo service varnish reload` to reload this rules without restarting Varnish. That means you won't loose your cache by performing a reload.